# Batch file to rename and move file to parent directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file that renames the first file in a folder to the name of the folder it's in and move that file to the folders parent directory.

**The problem** I'm facing is that if there are multiple files they all move out to parent directory. I only need to move that renamed file and not the rest.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("*.*") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        move *.* .. 2>NUL
    )
    POPD
)
Pause&Exit
```

I can't remember the source of the original code, but I was able to adjust it for my needs via `move *.* .. 2>NUL` but I'm not understanding if this can be even further adjusted for what I need now.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the `first file in a folder`? Why do you want/need to use a batch file? Do you know any programming languages? Which?

Comment: You can also add PowerShell there, which is easier to learn, as a note for the future. Also, don't reply with nonsense like "because of reasons" because that'll only lead to downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"

for /d /r %%i in =;(*)do 2>nul =;(
     dir /on /b /a:-d "%%~dpnxi\*.*" | find /v "" | find /v "%~nx0" >nul && =;(
     call %:^) "%%~dpnxi" && popd
    );=
    );=

goto :eOf

%:^)
pushd "%~1" && for /f delims^= %%G in =;(
    'dir /on /b /a:-d ".\*.*" ^| find /v "%~nx0"'
    );= do 2>nul move "%%~fG" "..\%~nx1%%~xG" & exit /b
```

---

**Obs.:** No need to rename first and then move, you can
rename in the same command that moves your file:

```bash
move "D:\Path\SomeOriginalFileName.txt" "D:\OtherPath\withTheNewFileName.txt"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`Goto /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Where does **`GOTO :EOF`** return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)